# Bootstrap modal gets closed on button click when used with OnServerClick ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

We are having requirement to use **bootstrap.css** in our **asp.net** application, we have encountered an issue with modals where modal gets closed when we click on a search button.

Follow is the button placed under the modal having id as "modal1"

```
 <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onserverclick="searchData">
     search
    </button>
```

One possible solution, may be I can do `$("#modal1").modal()` when the control comes back. But with this solution my modal refreshes and there is flickering every time I click on  a search button.

Can anybody help on how I can refresh the modal data.

Comment: so you want change data when modal is closed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Ajax concept.
I hope this would help u a little.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
 </asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show Modal Popup" />

<!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="btnShow" CancelControlID="btnClose" ackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center"   style = "display:none">
This is an ASP.Net AJAX ModalPopupExtender Example<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
</asp:Panel>
<!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I might get your problem you should try

```
$("#button-id").on("click",function(){
    //code
});
```

if still your modal is getting closed than put this code in the end of above function `$('#modal1').modal('show')`